# How to find coreset of a given dataset in python?

Tags: machine-learning, python, k-means, implementation

I am trying to implement the core-means algorithm, which is basically k-means using coreset. I have searched up and down but could not find any libraries or modules which could help me with this.

The paper I am following talks about building a coreset using grids, something like a quadtree where you keep dividing the point space in 4 equal parts to find heavy points which makes a coreset.

Any help would be greatly appreciated in getting me started as to how should I go about implementing this and if there are any libraries/modules available to help me do so.

PS: I'm new to python and machine learning and Hi StackExchange!

Comment: [Great paper I am currently studying](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=8501907).
There is a pseudocode for building coresets on page 8.

Comment: may be you can add the link to the paper or the talk ...

Answer (score 1):

Please check [here](https://github.com/mfyuce/k-segment/blob/master/tests/local_graph.py) for python 3 and  [here](https://github.com/vkhakham/k-segment/blob/master/spark_coreset-master/tests/local_graph.py) for python 2.

It works on an auto generated dataset, but it can be changed very easily.

Also, other libraries (I have not tried yet) you can check:

- [Accurate-coresets](https://github.com/ibramjub/Accurate-Coresets)
- [Bayesian-coresets](https://github.com/trevorcampbell/bayesian-coresets)
- [Coresets](https://github.com/zalanborsos/coresets)

Kindly let me know how it went.